# How to number by group?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I want to add "seq" column as numbering by group which is organized with BSTN, ASTN, O and D. 
This work is hard to me to classify as another group within the group.
A group is created whenever BSTN and O are equal, and ASTN and D are equal.

```
BSTN ASTN O D
150 202 150 151
150 202 151 201
150 202 201 202
150 202 150 426
150 202 426 423
150 202 423 321
150 202 321 320
150 202 320 203
150 202 203 202
150 403 150 426
150 403 426 423
150 403 423 321
150 403 321 320
150 403 320 403
150 403 150 151
150 403 151 201
150 403 201 403
150 403 150 426
150 403 426 422
150 403 422 205
150 403 205 403
```

in case of BSTN 150 to ASTN 202, it has two groups, since there are two 150s and 202s in O and D respectively.
The "seq" column what I want to is like this.

```
BSTN ASTN O D seq
150 202 150 151 1
150 202 151 201 1
150 202 201 202 1
150 202 150 426 2
150 202 426 423 2
150 202 423 321 2
150 202 321 320 2
150 202 320 203 2
150 202 203 202 2
150 403 150 426 1
150 403 426 423 1
150 403 423 321 1
150 403 321 320 1
150 403 320 403 1
150 403 150 151 2
150 403 151 201 2
150 403 201 403 2
150 403 150 426 3
150 403 426 422 3
150 403 422 205 3
150 403 205 403 3
```

please help me!!

Comment: Can you explain it more please? Your expected output is not consistent with your description

Comment: @Sotos BSTN and ASTN refer to the origin and destination. O and D are links on the path. There can be more than one route to BSTN and ASTN, and seq means the number of the route. Can you understand little bit??!  It's hard to explain!!!

Comment: well, I do now.... What you need is to look into a package called `igraph`

Comment: @Sotos Can you please, help this problem??!! I would really hopeful to solve it.

Comment: the way I interpret it, is that for each combination of BSTN and ASTN, a new group is created starting each time that O equals BSTN. Is that correct? Can you share your data by posting the output of `dput(df)` (where df is your data) or `dput(head(df,100))` if that would be too long?

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum You totally are right. that's what I want to!! I''m checking the way to share the df. just sec please.

Comment: The nicest way to share the data is to type `dput(df[1:20, ])` into your console and paste the result into the question. This makes a copy-pasteable representation of your data. (Of course, adjust the `1:20` to an appropriate number of rows, and exclude unnecessary columns if there are more...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(BSTN, ASTN) %>%
    mutate(g = lag(D) != O,
           g = if_else(is.na(g), FALSE, g),
           seq = cumsum(g) + 1)
# A tibble: 21 x 6
# Groups:   BSTN, ASTN [2]
    BSTN  ASTN     O     D g       seq
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <dbl>
 1   150   202   150   151 FALSE     1
 2   150   202   151   201 FALSE     1
 3   150   202   201   202 FALSE     1
 4   150   202   150   426 TRUE      2
 5   150   202   426   423 FALSE     2
 6   150   202   423   321 FALSE     2
 7   150   202   321   320 FALSE     2
 8   150   202   320   203 FALSE     2
 9   150   202   203   202 FALSE     2
10   150   403   150   426 FALSE     1
# ... with 11 more rows
```

You can, of course, remove the `g` column.

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = "BSTN ASTN O D
150 202 150 151
150 202 151 201
150 202 201 202
150 202 150 426
150 202 426 423
150 202 423 321
150 202 321 320
150 202 320 203
150 202 203 202
150 403 150 426
150 403 426 423
150 403 423 321
150 403 321 320
150 403 320 403
150 403 150 151
150 403 151 201
150 403 201 403
150 403 150 426
150 403 426 422
150 403 422 205
150 403 205 403", header = T)
```

Comment: Or maybe: `df %>% group_by(BSTN, ASTN) %>% mutate(seq = cumsum(lag(D, default = TRUE) != O))`?

Comment: @Jaap I think that `default = TRUE` will be essentially coerced to `default = 1` (since `D` is numeric), so that will break if `O` takes value `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I attempt another way with `tapply()` to make groups.

```
attach(df)

tapply(O, list(BSTN, ASTN), function(x) cumsum(x == x[1]) ) %>% unlist

  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
 [38] 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
 [75] 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1
```

It gets the same output as the first answer. Hope to help you.

Comment: I'd recommend using `with` rather than `attach` - `attach`ing can cause a lot of problems.